# I want to create tables in Django database by which may have dynamic fields by uploading a excel or csv sheet from a web interface

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

1. How can we create a DB table in db using django framework by
   uploading a unique CSV/excel files

   In front end there will be an upload button for uploading a CSV/excel and once user clicks​ submit a table should be created based on the fields in file uploaded
   Help me on django dynamic models (if it can be implemented)

note: the columns may contain  fields of different datatype like int,CharField

Answer (score 0):

You can use Django import-export feature, or ImportExportModelAdmin.

Comment: import export may work for upload CSV file into predefined model.but I want dynamic fields